# Error ActionController::UnknownFormat returned when rendering partial onclick with link_to in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render a new view to my div onclick with link_to. But once i click the link, it gives me an error message ActionController::UnknownFormat.

The following is the error log,

```
Started GET "/load_poc" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-13 20:29:58 +0000
Processing by IndexController#load_poc as HTML
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 0ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/index_controller.rb:7:in `load_poc'
```

Can you please tell me how to fix this problem? Is this a routing issue or am I missing some important steps?
Thank you very much!

Following is my code:

## index.html.haml

```
= link_to "#{@xx}", load_poc_path(@xx), :remote => true, :method => :get

#poc waiting...
```

## _load_poc.js.erb

```
$('#poc').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'poc') %>");
```

## index_controller.rb

```
def load_poc
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

## routes.rb

```
match 'load_poc', :to => IndexController.action("load_poc"), via: 'get'
```

Answer (score 0):

`Processing by IndexController#load_poc as HTML` is the problem. Your action is only responding to requests as JS, but it's sending through as an HTML request. Your request should look like: `Processing by IndexController#load_poc as JS`